# Select the even rows from the table and change the column value in sequence

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2012

I have the following table from that i needs to choose only the even row DocEntry, So i am using the query "select * from Test3 where DocEntry%2 = 0" and get it.

[image]

Query Resuslt,

[image]

In the result i needs to change the DocEntry columns as '1727102921','1727102922','1727102923','1727102924','1727102925' instead of the same DocEntry. Please help me on this.

Comment: Add a tag of the sql language you're using

Comment: I'm using sql server 2012

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select 
    *
    ,min(DocEntry) over ()-1+row_number() over (order by DocEntry asc) NewDocEntry
from Test3 
where DocEntry%2 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my suggestion:

```
DECLARE @baseNumber int = 1727102920;
WITH #even AS (
    SELECT * FROM YourTable WHERE DocEntry % 2 = 0
)
SELECT (DocEntry - @baseNumber)/2 + @baseNumber DocEntry, Name
FROM #even
```

Start by defining your base number (**1727102920**), then dividing by two the difference from actual "DocEntry" and your base number, and summing the two:

```
1727102922=> Difference: 2 => base +1 => 1727102921
1727102924=> Difference: 4 => base +2 => 1727102922
1727102926=> Difference: 6 => base +3 => 1727102923
1727102928=> Difference: 8 => base +4 => 1727102924
1727102930=> Difference: 10 => base +5 => 1727102925
```

This way, you should also get good performance for greater number of rows.